# JCrop - functionality doesn't get implemented

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle, jcrop

I want to use JCrop to crop an image.
I tried implementing a very simple useage on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5ptqrbw/).

I included JQuery, JCrop and the JCrop CSS using CDN-Links.

This is my code:

**HEADER:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jcrop-cdn.tapmodo.com/v2.0.0-RC1/js/Jcrop.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jcrop-cdn.tapmodo.com/v2.0.0-RC1/css/Jcrop.css" type="text/css">
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <img src="http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos/demo_files/sago.jpg" id="cropTarget" />
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  initJCrop();          
});
function initJCrop() {
  $('#cropTarget').Jcrop({bgColor: "black",bgOpacity: .4,aspectRatio: 100 / 130,setSelect: [200, 260, 50, 50]});
}
</script>
```

As you can see, in my JSFiddle, it simply shows a "normal" image and I can't get JCrop to work.

What I've tried:

- Check if CDN-Links are working.
- Try different JS-Code (Including [the one from the JCrop Quickstart Guide](http://jcrop.org/doc/quickstart))
- Without `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Check the console. The script include is blocked because it's not via a secure domain, ie. `https://`. You also have several syntax issues. Once you fix those problems, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/c5ptqrbw/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You editet your comment to fast, sry. Your linked example doesn't seem to work in my google chrome and ms edge. It still behaves like a normal image.

Comment: That's strange as it's fine here in Chrome 47.0 on W8. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan A lot of errors there. ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE for the js and css and ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT followed by "Jcrop is not a function". Is this the fault of my browser? It doesn't work on my phone either.

Comment: Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c5ptqrbw/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Still not working. I'll try at home, maybe there's something wrong in my office^^

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not working. Tried on MS Surface Pro 4 with Google Chrome. Still the same errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by my self:

1) Change - `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

To: - `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

2) Move the JS from the header to the bottom of the body (right before the `<\body>`-Tag).

Somehow my `$(document).ready(function() {..})`-part didn't work and `initJcrop()` was never called.